# How to log time and date data from batch file to a .log file upon execution

Tags: batch-file

I want to log the current date and time to a separate log file upon the initiation of my batch file. What i have so far:

```
date | mylogfile.log
time | mylogfile.log

echo i will now create a temp file in the c drive

md c:\myTemp

cd c:\myTemp

cd c:\"program Files (x86)\"Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"\"Common7"\IDE

devenv.exe

pause
```

So it does log it BUT it is opening my log file and making the user press enter before the batch file is executed. All i want is the date and time to be logged into the file and nothing else. My issue is within my first two lines.

Comment: A good idea is to read help. So type `date /?` and `time /?`. A second thing you may not know and difficult to find is you pipe to programs not files. So you need to fix the date/time commands and redirect them with `>>` to a file.

Comment: so the date and time commands do not work in this scenario?

Comment: Read help and you'll find out.

Comment: ahh i need to use the T switch to just display output and not prompt for a new date!

Comment: Correct. And redirect instead of piping. See my answer here for a CMD cheat sheet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371443/what-do-all-commands-in-batch-mean-and-do

Comment: @Noodles would you like to post the answer down below so i can check it off or can i answer my own question? I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Answer your own question. I was teaching to look in help first, it's easier. And that's before writing anything - you get a feel for what options are open to you. Every command has options incl `Dir`, `copy`, and even `cd`.

Comment: This command dumps most of help. `For /f %A in ('help') Do %A /?`

Comment: hopefully this isn't a complicated question. Can i check weather another batch file has been executed within this batch file?

Comment: Put it in a new question. And as you aren't actually running another batchfile (in the code above) say exactly what you mean. Also your quotes are wrong in the last CD command. Quotes go around the entire path, not in the middle of it. `"C:\some folder\some file.exe"`.

Comment: A really good idea is running in a command prompt window `set /?` and read the output help pages especially the last one which lists `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` which can be used in a command line like `echo %DATE% %TIME%>>mylogfile.log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To log date and time data use date /T >> and time /T >>

```
date /T >> mylogfile.log
time /T >> mylogfile.log

echo i will now create a temp file in the c drive

md c:\myTemp

cd c:\myTemp

cd "c:\program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE"

devenv.exe

pause
```

Comment: `cd "c:\program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE"`. Entire path includes the drive letter.

Comment: Usage of `date /T and `time /T` is IMO deprecated there are [internal Variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) `%date% %time%` with thte same formatting and they can be used in a single echo command. To learn more on this [visit ss.64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/)